# How can I create this using a for loop in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried creating this using a for loop but couldn't get working

```js
let ifCounterExists0 = localStorage.getItem('counter0');
let ifCounterExists1 = localStorage.getItem('counter1');
let ifCounterExists2 = localStorage.getItem('counter2');
let ifCounterExists3 = localStorage.getItem('counter3');
let ifCounterExists4 = localStorage.getItem('counter4');
let ifCounterExists5 = localStorage.getItem('counter5');
let ifCounterExists6 = localStorage.getItem('counter6');
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Additionally... Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/328193)  You are encouraged to make an attempt.  If during your attempt you encounter a specific problem, such as a specific operation producing an error or an unexpected result, we can help with that.

Comment: `But it doesn't work.` ... Did you declare `a` before your loop? e.g. `let a = [];`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple for loop that will add all the document selectors into the array from which later you can access them using the index of the array. Also the loop is set to 6 iteration, do adjust it accordingly.

```
const adds = [];
for(let i = 0; i<6; i++) {
    adds.push(document.querySelector(`.add${i}`));
}
adds[0];
```

We can you javascript template syntax for using js variables inside a string. Hope this resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it. You have a typo in your `for` loop and you should declare your array before the loop. And, since the loop will populate the array with node lists, there's no reason to create them ahead of time.

```js
let add = [];

for(let i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
    add[i] = document.querySelector('.add' + i);
}

console.log(add[0]);
console.log(add[1]);
console.log(add[2]);
console.log(add[3]);
console.log(add[4]);
console.log(add[5]);
console.log(add[6]);
```

```html
<div class="add0"></div>
<span class="add1"></span>
<p class="add2"></p>
<section class="add3"></v>
<article class="add4"></article>
<aside class="add5"></aside>
<h1 class="add6"></h1>
```